# Dlookup will not work with navigation and subforms

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have a simple form that uses the following code to auto-populate 2 comboboxes based on the selection in the first:

```
Private Sub Planner_Name_AfterUpdate()

Dim FormTrade As Variant, FormFLS As Variant

FormTrade = DLookup("Trade", "Planners", "[PlannerName] = Forms!EstimateForm!PlannerName")
FormFLS = DLookup("FLS", "Planners", "[PlannerName] = Forms!EstimateForm!PlannerName")

Me.Trade = FormTrade
Me.FLS = FormFLS

End Sub
```

This is based on a table with 3 fields: PlannerName, Trade, FLS

This way, when someone knows the Planner's name, it will automatically fill in their Trade and the FLS who is running the job.

Everything works fine until I make this form a sub in a navigation form and then it quits working.

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accounting for the fact that the form is no longer an open form but infact it is now a Navigation SubForm. You will need to edit your code to account for the sub form

```
Current DLookup
FormTrade = DLookup("Trade", "Planners", "[PlannerName] = Forms!EstimateForm!PlannerName")
Modified DLookup
FormTrade = DLookup("Trade", "Planners", "[PlannerName] = [Forms]![frm_navigation]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![EstimateForm]![PlannerName]")
```

My answer is based on a guess that your subform is names frm_Navigation. But to get the exact name. Open a New Query and add any table and any field (not important) then right click and select build... in the expression builder. Open the + sign next to your database and then Forms --> Loaded Forms --> your form name your --> navigation subform name --> and your control box.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Your suggestion to use the expression builder to find the exact name of the control box really helped.  It turns out you don't have to refer to the name of the subform at all, just the name of the control after identifying it is in the subform.